# POST data using JSON, REST, Spring Boot JAVA

Tags: java, json, spring

I am trying to make a post request using JSON and  spring boot @RestController. I am testing CRUD operations but have some issues with POST. I have copied the exception which i have bellow. Hpe someone will help.

```
 public class MuscleCar {

        private int id;
        private String carBrand;
        private String carModel;
        private int horsepower;
        private String carEngine;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getCarBrand() {
            return carBrand;
        }

        public void setCarBrand(String carBrand) {
            this.carBrand = carBrand;
        }

        public String getCarModel() {
            return carModel;
        }

        public void setCarModel(String carModel) {
            this.carModel = carModel;
        }


        public String getCarEngine() {
            return carEngine;
        }

        public void setCarEngine(String carEngine) {
            this.carEngine = carEngine;
        }

        public int getHorsepower() {
            return horsepower;
        }

        public void setHorsepower(int horsepower) {
            this.horsepower = horsepower;
        }
```

**Method from DAO**

```
@Override
public List<MuscleCar> addCarToList(MuscleCar muscleCar) {
    String sql = "insert into muscle_cars (car_brand, car_model, horsepower, car_engine) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    Object[] args = new Object[] {muscleCar.getCarBrand(), muscleCar.getCarModel(), muscleCar.getHorsepower(), muscleCar.getCarEngine()};
    return getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, args, new MuscleCarRowMapper());
}
```

**Method from Resource**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add-car", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<List<MuscleCar>> addCarToList(MuscleCar muscleCar) {

    try {
        List<MuscleCar> mc = m.addCarToList(muscleCar);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(mc);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into muscle_cars (car_brand, car_model, horsepower, car_engine) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:108)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:684)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:716)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:726)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:776)
        at com.scar.dao.MuscleCarDaoImpl.addCarToList(MuscleCarDaoImpl.java:42)
        at com.scar.dao.MuscleCarDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$14c1a4cb.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
        at com.scar.dao.MuscleCarDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9db5f83a.addCarToList(<generated>)
        at com.scar.resource.MuscleCarResource.addCarToList(MuscleCarResource.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkForDml(StatementImpl.java:463)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1923)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:692)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
        ... 56 more
```

**EDIT:**
I have changed with update query. Now when i try to post JSON i have this exception. I thin that when i try to POST the JSON the fields o MuscleCar object are never initialize but i do not know how to initialize them.

**JSON**

```
{
    "carBrand":"BMW",
    "carModel":"530",
    "hoursepower":250,
    "carEngine":"M-Power V8"
}
```

**Exception:**

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into muscle_cars (car_brand, car_model, horsepower, car_engine) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; Column 'car_brand' cannot be null; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'car_brand' cannot be null
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:85)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:931)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:941)
    at com.scar.dao.MuscleCarDaoImpl.addCarToList(MuscleCarDaoImpl.java:42)
    at com.scar.dao.MuscleCarDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$14c1a4cb.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at com.scar.dao.MuscleCarDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9db5f83a.addCarToList(<generated>)
    at com.scar.resource.MuscleCarResource.addCarToList(MuscleCarResource.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I try to POST the JSON the fields o MuscleCar object are never
>   initialize but i do not know how to initialize them.

You need to add `@RequestBody` to the controller method so that the `MuscleCar` object will be populated with the incoming request json data.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add-car", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<List<MuscleCar>> 
        addCarToList(@RequestBody MuscleCar muscleCar) {
    try {
       List<MuscleCar> mc = m.addCarToList(muscleCar);
       return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(mc);
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `JdbcTemplate.query()` the [update](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update(java.lang.String)) method should be used for writing operations.

This would then use the JDBC method `executeUpdate` instead of `executeQuery`, which is the reason for the message:

> Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()